# How to compare nested collections in swift

Tags: swift

I have two collections:

```
let collection1:[String:[String:NSObject]] = ["somekey":["nestedkey":"value"]]

let collection2:[String:[String:NSObject]] = ["somekey":["nestedkey":"value"]]

//I would like to compare them using the following:

let collectionsAreEqual = collection1 == collection2
```

Copying and pasting the above code into a playground gives the following error:

[image]

I know I can write an equal function for this:

```
infix func == (this:[String:[String:NSObject]], that:[String:[String:NSObject]]){
    //return true or false
}
```

In objective c, isEqual: on an NSDictionary handles this no problem, because it does the nested comparison for you. Is there some method of generally handling this in swift?

**Update**

I can use the following:

```
//:[String:[String:NSObject]]
let collection1:[String:NSObject] = ["somekey":["nestedkey":"value"]]

let collection2:[String:NSObject] = ["somekey":["nestedkey":"value"]]
//I would like to compare them using the following:

let collectionsAreEqual = collection1 == collection2
```

but it requires using NSObject as the value in the declaration. Is there a pure swift method to handle this?

Comment: The pure Swift method is to write that custom operator -- the only built-in `==` that applies to dictionaries requires that the values be `Equatable`, which dictionaries and arrays are not. Even though `==` can be used with arrays and dictionaries under certain conditions, that doesn't mean they conform to `Equatable`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an equality operator that will compare any two nested dictionaries with the same type:

```
func ==<T: Equatable, K1: Hashable, K2: Hashable>(lhs: [K1: [K2: T]], rhs: [K1: [K2: T]]) -> Bool {
    if lhs.count != rhs.count { return false }

    for (key, lhsub) in lhs {
        if let rhsub = rhs[key] {
            if lhsub != rhsub {
                return false
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this in my unit testing and it's giving me an error saying "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'" Is operator overloading not usable in unit testing?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem - where is the function declared? Operator functions have to be at the top level (outside any class or type declaration).

Comment: Ah, that's my problem. I had it inside the Tests class.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let collection1:[String:NSObject] = ["somekey":["nestedkey":"value"]]

let collection2:[String:NSObject] = ["somekey":["nestedkey":"value"]]

let collectionsAreEqual = ((collection1 as NSDictionary).isEqual(collection2 as NSDictionary)
```

By casting the swift objects to Foundation objects they get the equality operator. They will call the equality operator on every element recursively, so there you have your deep comparison.